# Bulk Redirect through HTAccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a large amount of urls that are very similar to a single url so an example would be;

engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond-engagement-rings-4.html

engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond-engagement-rings-5.html

engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond-engagement-rings-6.html

engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond-engagement-rings-7.html

Would need to redirect to

/engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond.html

is there a simple bit of code that I could use to redirect?

e.g 
Redirect 301 /engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond-engagement-rings-(*).html http://www.website.co.uk/engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond.html

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` directive doesn't accept Regular Expressions.

Use `RedirectMatch` directive instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond).+?\.html$ /$1
```

**OR else** you can use this `mod_rewrite` rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond).+?\.html$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: This didn't work, is it due to the fact that the old url is;
engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond-engagement-rings-NUMBER.html
and the new is
engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond.html?

So its missing the -engagement-rings on the new url as well as the number

Comment: But you said new URL is: `engagement-rings/marquise-cut-diamond.html` I don't see `-engagement-rings` and number in new URI